# Not understanding control flow of JavaScript WebSocket (using React)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, websocket

Using web sockets in React (TypeScript), I'm a bit confused over the control flow of the web socket object.

The `WebSocket` object requires the URL to the web socket. It presumably connects immediately.

But only after having created the object and presumably connected to the web socket, the `onopen` and `onmessage` events are configured. This is how every single tutorial and explanation I've seen online does things.

What I don't really understand, is why it works. In my test code (shown below), it works fine, and it always logs in properly and always receives the message. But it seems to me that there is a built-in race condition that sooner or later is going to show itself.

I've looked online for ways to configure a `WebSocket` object but connect to it **later** setting the parameters, but found nothing.

There are two reasons I'm asking.

One is that I don't understand how this code avoids a race condition where the connection is successful **before** the `onopen` event is configured.

The other is that I would like to keep the web socket object somewhere central (using atoms in Jotai, if it matters), but I don't necessarily want to connect to the web socket at the same time that I create the object. In other words, I would very much like to create the object first, and then connect with a `connect` function or some equivalent. I've found no such thing to be available in JavaScript's WebSocket.

Can someone please explain to me what I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

```
    const webSocket = new WebSocket(constants.WS_URI);
    webSocket.onopen = (event) => {
      webSocket.send(
        JSON.stringify({
          command: "login",
          token: "Bearer " + user.token,
        })
      );
    };
    webSocket.onmessage = (event) => {
      const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
      console.log("**" + data.username + "**: " + data.message + "\n");
    };
```

Comment: There are no race conditions in javascript. The language is single-threaded by definition. In your example that means that `onopen` and `onmessage` are guaranteed to be assigned to before the async action of establishing a connection occurs.

Comment: @yeahwhat: Yes, it does! Totally missed that! Thanks!

Comment: @super: If it were a race condition, it wouldn't be based on JavaScript being multi-threaded but on the nature of using an external resource like a network. It has been explained why the race condition doesn't exist, but it absolutely could have been there even if JavaScript is single-threaded.